# How to asynchronously load Scripts using Browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

Can we load external JS like:

```
var modal = require("http://localhost:9000/modal.js");
```

Is this achievable using Browserify

Comment: Did you try it? if yes, what was the result? if not, try it and share the result.

Comment: I get error saying the specified file is not found in your local files.
My original intention is to load reactjs component via ajax.

Comment: i think that it isnt possible with `browserify`. Why you can't save the react component local instead?

Comment: Because this component comes from another source.